# How can I transform Entity-Based diagram to a JPA java code

Tags: jpa, enterprise-architect, mda

I have class diagram created with "Sparx Enterprise Architect v8.0" and i need to generate JPA-based classes with annotations that reflect relations to use it in the code. 
The problem is that i can convert it to EJB but not JPA which is required for my task.

Comment: if you are interested in MDA I would invite you to follow this stack overflow like QA group dedicated to MDA topics [>MDA<](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36533/model-driven-architecture).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know this product, however they [claim](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) that it:

> supports modeling of database schema and automatic generation of DDL scripts for eleven DBMS targets out-of-the-box

Once you have the database schema I believe there are various tools that can reverse engineer it and generate JPA entities. Few random hits in Google:

- [Generating Persistence Mappings from Database Schema](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/jpa_hibernate.html#link5)
- [Creating JPA entity beans from database tables](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.jpa.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_jpa_bottomup.html)
- [Object-Relational Mappings: Generating JPA Entities](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.orm.doc/html/files/genJPAEntities.html)

Comment: Dear Tomasz, 
Thank you for your response, actually I not am looking for reverse engineering, the Idea is generating the database schema and DAO classes from class diagram.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough and you misunderstood me. I don't know *Sparx Enterprise Architect*, but it can generate database schema for you (DDL script, see quote above), and from DDL script (existing databse schema) you can easily create JPA entities with various tools (see links).

Comment: If you find this approach helpful consider accepting an answer. Otherwise please provide more detail so me and other could think about it more.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [JPA Modeler](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53057/jpa-modeler) for Netbeans, will be best fit for your requirement :

> generate the database schema and DAO classes from class diagram

You can find the demo here : [JPA Modeler Demo - Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8B764qNkc0)

Answer (score 0):

If you  export your model to ecore format, then you can use [Texo](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Texo) to generate JPA annotated POJO for your model.

Answer (score 0):

G9 plugin from Marketplace in Spring Tool Suit did job.

1. Install Plugin G9
2. Select Project (JAVA)
3. Import "Import Database Model"
4. Select JDBC Driver (In my case mysql)
5. Maintain JDBC Connection

   - New
   - Provide *Driver Name, Add Jar, Port, Driver Class and connection url along with schema (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{schema_name})*
6. Close JDBC Connection Box
7. Port, DB Name, User Name and PWD
8. Fetch

Reference URL https://www.esito.no/produkter/dbimport/