# Tool to generate a ERD (entity-relation diagram) based on JPA annotations

Tags: java, orm, erd

I'm writing a java code using ormlite. I was wondering if it's possible to generate an ERD from the JPA annotations in my code. Basically, I need the reverse of this: [How can I transform Entity-Based diagram to a JPA java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202231/how-can-i-transform-entity-based-diagram-to-a-jpa-java-code)

Comment: Can't you let JPA create the tables and then generate the ERD from the actual database?

Comment: That's a possibility. You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488/auto-generate-database-diagram-mysql right? But It'd be better if is possible to generate ERD directly from java codes.

Answer (score 16):

IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate) provides JPA to ER-Diagram generator.

[image: context menu]

In the Persistence tool window, select appropriate node. Then use context menu to select "ER Diagram".

[image: sample ER diagram]

Note that JPA facet must be linked to module and UML plugin should be active.