# Create Data model from entity classes using plantuml

Tags: jpa, plantuml

I am planning to use JPA Entities to create my data model. As part of the design , we have been asked to document the data model and keep them updated. I was asked to used plantUml to create the Database model, but I would like to see how to get started on converting the JPA Entity--> plantuml macro code --> Data model. Seeking out help to see how I can tackle this request

Comment: Is it something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187048/tool-to-generate-a-erd-entity-relation-diagram-based-on-jpa-annotations

Comment: @Rjiuk This helps, I was looking for more of java class into plant uml macro, but JPA to ER diagram also helps

Answer (score 3):

You can build your model Structurizr and then export them to PlantUML.

https://github.com/structurizr/java-extensions/blob/master/docs/plantuml.md